# connect php to mysql community server

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have both `xampp`, `mysql community server` Installed on my `Ubuntu 22.04`.
since both `xampp/phpmyadmin` and `mysql community server` listen to `port 3306`,
I have changed `mysqli.default_port=3307` in `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini` and I have also added a line right under `[mysql]` in `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf` saying `port = 3307`.
Now I have also extracted hostname from my mysql using this commands

```
service mysql start
mysql -u root -p
show variables like '%host%';
```

which said my host name is
`solo-ROG-Strix-G731GV-G731GV`
and I also created a user with all grants on a database like

```
create database test;
create user 'test'@'solo-ROG-Strix-G731GV-G731GV' identified by '1234';
grant all privileges on test.* to 'test'@'solo-ROG-Strix-G731GV-G731GV';
flush privileges
```

and then I made sure phpmysqladmin was not running by only running xamppapache using

```
cd /opt/lampp/
sudo ./xampp startapache
```

and here is my php code to connect to mysql community server

```
<?php
const MYSQLI_HOSTNAME = "solo-ROG-Strix-G731GV-G731GV";
const MYSQLI_ADMIN_USERNAME = "test";
const MYSQLI_ADMIN_PASSWORD = "1234";
const MYSQLI_DATABASE = "test";
$db_admin = new mysqli(MYSQLI_HOSTNAME, MYSQLI_ADMIN_USERNAME,
    MYSQLI_ADMIN_PASSWORD, MYSQLI_DATABASE
, 3307);

if($db_admin->connect_error){
    echo $db_admin->connect_error;
}
```

and now it's saying `connection refused`

full error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Connection refused in /opt/lampp/htdocs/baharshop/src/lib/db/db_admin.php:2 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/baharshop/src/lib/db/db_admin.php(2): mysqli->__construct('solo-ROG-Strix-...', 'test', Object(SensitiveParameterValue), 'test', 3307) #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/baharshop/config/config_admin.php(17): require_once('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/baharshop/admin/dashboard.php(3): require_once('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #3 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/baharshop/src/lib/db/db_admin.php on line 2`
```

I mean what else needs to be done?

I tried changing ports on both php.ini and mysql community server

Comment: Do you need host restriction? If not, replace `solo-ROG-Strix-G731GV-G731GV` with a wildcard (`%`) and move on: `grant all privileges on test.* to 'test'@'%' identified by '1234';` (`create user` and `flush` should not be needed) and you should be good.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin most certainly does not listen on port 3306. It's just a web app

Answer (score 1):

I ended up changing xampp/mysql/phpmyadmin port because that was easier
and left the the mysql community workbench to have it's default port
since I was on linux it was harder to locate mysql community workbench config files.
it might help someone in future

Answer (score 0):

port = 3307 should be in the [mysqld] option in the parameter file, not [mysql]. Changing the port requires restarting the database service.